# Getting inactivity/idle time in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I was looking for the best approach to find out the if my users are idle in my WPF application. Currently, I take this idle time from operating system, and if they minimize the application, and go and search in Internet, there is a process in the operating system, so Operation system does not consider this as inactivity time even though they are not doing anything inside the application. However, I would like to find out if they have not clicked or do anything inside my application.

This is how I can that idle time right now.

```
myApplication.MainMethod()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        myTimer .Interval = 1000;
        myTimer .Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        myTimer .Start();
    }

    void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int idleTime= (int)Win32.GetIdleTime();
        if (idleTime<certainNumber)
        {
         //do this
         }
    }
```

Comment: See [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744980/hide-mouse-cursor-after-an-idle-time/745227#745227) to another question regarding idle time for a nice solution.

Answer (score 19):

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += new System.EventHandler(ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle);
    }

void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do your idle stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

See this answer:
[Application.Idle event not firing in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344398/application-idle-event-not-firing-in-wpf-application)

ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle is the event you are looking for.

Comment: +1, but might not be what the question wants. A user being idle usually means not using mouse or keyboard. The dispatcher also dispatches things like a timer so might be less idle than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

1. For such scenarios, we need a `Timer` which fires back some `event` after a `timeinterval`.
2. And most importantly, we need a `callback / eventhandler` which gets called everytime any activity of any kind happens in our application, so that we know that our application is `running`.

Point 1 can be handled using `DispatcherTimer`.

Point 2 can be handled using `public event CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler CanExecute;` .

Putting it altogether :

***MainWindow.xaml***

> xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input; 
>   assembly=Presentationcore"

```
    <!-- a do nothing button -->
    <Button  Command="{x:Static cmd:NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Button.CommandBindings>
    <!-- we can use any pre-defined / user-defined command -->
            <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static cmd:NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1"/>
        </Button.CommandBindings>
    </Button>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
    public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
        bool running = true;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute_1(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            running = true;
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!running)
                App.Current.Shutdown();

            running = false;
        }
    }
```

We can easily extend this approach to fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about subscribing to [SENS](http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/105651) events?

Here's [another link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301850.aspx).

Comment: I would like to control everything internally without calling/querying an external service.