# Idle time using DispatcherTimer - Not Working

Tags: wpf, python-idle, dispatchertimer

I have an application all done in WPF, using MvvM/Prism/Unity and Remote as datasource.

I need a basic thing that on win forms is really easy, just check if the app is iddle after few minutes , and if is idle, lock the app and show the login screen.

After some search on google I ´ve found one solution that uses DllImport and another using pure Wpf methods.

I don´t know I , after I implemented the Wpf way (pls check the code below) it only works after I login into the app , if I open and click in a simple texbox or hit a search, the idle method is not fired, looks like there is something hanged in the background that makes Wpf idle routine to think that it´s doing something when it´s not.

How can I check all the services/methods/etc.. that are in memory related to may app ? callstack doesn´t show to much for me. I am affraid that or I am not calling in the correct way the remote services or I implemented something wrong on the props PropChanged events/observablecollections/etc...

Is there a better way to do this using 100% Wpf structure ?

```
private void CheckIdleTime()
{

    handler = delegate
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                timer = null;
                System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle -= handler;

                Console.WriteLine("IDLE! Lets logoff!");

                this.LockApplication();

                Console.WriteLine("logoff fired");

                System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += handler;
            }

        };

        timer.Start();


        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted += delegate
        {
            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                timer = null;
            }
        };
    };

    ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += handler;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be default window events find the idle time... i think it will be wise if we use same events for wpf or any other applications...

following link will help you to implement it..

[Application.Idle event not firing in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344398/application-idle-event-not-firing-in-wpf-application)

Comment: Thanks Jan, my main problem is that something in my app I am not consuming/releasing in the correct way, making some object stuck in memory, so when I use the correct methods to check if there is something running in background they return TRUE when should be FALSE. I used a traditional ImportDll routine and it´s working fine. Cheers