# Pausing window wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, action

I'd like to play a video when no mouse action is launch and the cursor is not moving for 10 seconds.
I tried this code:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.Show();
        }

        public void declencher() {
            try
            {
                while (Mouse.Captured != null)
                {
                    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
                    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 12);
                    dispatcherTimer.Start();
                    MessageBox.Show("hhh");
                }
            }
            catch { }


        }
```

I'd like to know how can i test this condition in WPF and what is the best method to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code

```
 if (button1.Content.Equals("Play"))
            {
                button1.Content = "Pause";
                mediaElement1.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Content = "Play";
                mediaElement1.Pause();
            }
```

Comment: No i mean the condition ( testing no mouse action and no cursor action is launched in 10 secondes ) to show another window that contains the video

Comment: you mean to say App has to wait for 10 Second to Load the Video,

Comment: try with this Test for Mouse.Captured!= null.

Comment: i have a wpf application is running . When user didn't done any thing in 10 seconds( cursor and mouse not moving) another window appears and cover the first one and it contains for example a full screen video

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways and seems all are discussed in other threads
The methods are using combination of ,InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput = timer,ApplicationIdle event dispatcher or Win32 calls. If you didn't try these, please do.

[WPF inactivity and activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963135/wpf-inactivity-and-activity),
[Getting inactivity/idle time in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111615/getting-inactivity-idle-time-in-a-wpf-)
application
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/811f5706-b9d7-414c-a590-cb9f6108b564
http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2011/03/19/detecting-idle-time-with-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-wpf.aspx

I hope you are already aware of playing videos in WPF.

Comment: see plz the update : how can i replace Mouse.captured because it didn't working