# Hide mouse cursor on OS X after a few seconds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cursor, python-idle

For my fullscreen app, I want to hide the cursor after a few seconds if it's not moved, like the fullscreen mode in QuickTime or iTunes. Presumably I'm looking to call `[NSCursor setHiddenUntilMouseMoves:YES]`, but how do I know when to call it?

Presumably I'm looking for the same as [Hide mouse cursor after an idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744980/hide-mouse-cursor-after-an-idle-time) but on the Mac. I couldn't find a way to get similar a "idle time". (Plus, I probably don't care about keyboard events, just mouse movement.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the time the cursor (and if you want also the keyboard) has been idle using:
`CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState, kCGEventMouseMoved)`

Swift 3 code:
`CGEventSource.secondsSinceLastEventType(CGEventSourceStateID.combinedSessionState, eventType: CGEventType.mouseMoved)`

See also http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html. You're probably going to have to poll this function every couple of seconds, and you should assume the user moved the cursor if the time returned has decreased.

Comment: Polling that would be less efficient than just resetting a one-time timer when the mouse moves, though. A timer doesn't consume any CPU time except when it fires; the corollary to that is that a timer that fires only once uses less CPU time than a timer that fires repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

What about using NSTimer and check after n seconds whether nothing has happened?

Comment: But how can you tell whether nothing has happened?

Comment: Ben Alpert: When something does happen, set a flag. When the timer fires, check the flag. If you haven't set it, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)`, for e.g.:

```
import Cocoa

class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {

    private var mouseTimer: Timer?
    private var mouseTimeOut: Float = 1.0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        mouseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(mouseTimeOut),
                                          target: self,
                                          selector: #selector(hideMouse),
                                          userInfo: nil,
                                          repeats: true)
    }

    // MARK: - Mouse Cursor
    @objc func hideMouse() {
        if Float(CGEventSource.secondsSinceLastEventType(CGEventSourceStateID.combinedSessionState, eventType: CGEventType.mouseMoved)) > mouseTimeOut {
            NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
        }
    }
}
```