# Hide mouse cursor after certain inactive mouse time in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make the mouse cursor disappear after a certain time when the mouse isn't moving. [There's already a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744980/hide-mouse-cursor-after-an-idle-time) but the WebBrowser Control form doesn't have Mouse events. I have this code that was mentioned on the question linked above:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public TimeSpan TimeoutToHide { get; private set; }
public DateTime LastMouseMove { get; private set; }
public bool IsHidden { get; private set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TimeoutToHide = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
}

void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LastMouseMove = DateTime.Now;

    if (IsHidden) 
    { 
        Cursor.Show(); 
        IsHidden = false; 
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan elaped = DateTime.Now - LastMouseMove;
    if (elaped >= TimeoutToHide && !IsHidden)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        IsHidden = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebBrowserControl` doesn't support `MouseMove` event. Instead you can use [`MouseMove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) event of [`WebBrowser.Document.Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then apply the logic which you are using for showing and hiding cursor. In a timer `Tick` event check if the last movement was before a specific time, hide the cursor using [`Cursor.Hide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx). Also in `MouseMove` show the cursor using [`Cursor.Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.show(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
DateTime? lastMovement;
bool hidden = false;
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.MouseMove += Document_MouseMove;
}
void Document_MouseMove(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    lastMovement = DateTime.Now;
    if (hidden)
    {
        Cursor.Show();
        hidden = false;
    }
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!lastMovement.HasValue)
        return;
    TimeSpan elaped = DateTime.Now - lastMovement.Value;
    if (elaped >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) && !hidden)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        hidden = true;
    }
}
```

**Note**

- The job of `bool hidden` is to keep balance between `Show` and `Hide`, because as mentioned in documentations:

  > The Show and Hide method calls must be balanced. For every call to the
  >   Hide method there must be a corresponding call to the Show method.
- Subscribe for `MouseMove` when the document completed, because `Document` would be null before completing `DocumentCompleted` event raise.
- I checked if `lastMovement` doesn't have value then didn't hide the cursor, to prevent hiding the cursor at startup before the user moves mouse over the control.

Comment: Thank you so much @RezaAghaei but the code is not working for me... The cursor stays shown...

Comment: You can simply arrange a test in a clean environment. **1)** Create a `Form`. **2)** Put a `WebBrowser` on form. **3)** Put a `Timer` on form and set its `interval` to `300` and its `Enabled` to `true` **4)** Attach `Load` event of form to `Form1_Load`. **5)**  Attach `DocumentCompleted` event of web browser to `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`  **6)** Attach `Tick` event of timer to `timer1_Tick`. **7)** Run the program and move the mouse over web browser, don't move for about seconds and then move again and see the result.

Comment: Ok! My problem was than I didn't enable the timer. Thank you so much again. Perfect answer!

Comment: Reza, I just realized that if I'm focused to flash elements on the webbrowser, the cursor stays shown, do you know why?

Comment: Hmm, currently I don't have any idea about the flash. *Maybe* the flash active-x has its own control over the cursor. If you couldn't solve the problem with flash, post a new question containing reproduction steps containing a URL to reproduce the problem and I'll take a look at that :)

Comment: I'll try making some research, I reach you later, thanks.

Comment: I tested it using a flash game and it seems it doesn't work on flash, the same way that the cursor is visible outside of your form, the cursor is always visible over flash game.